# How to evaluate the coefficient in this expression?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

> If the coefficient of $x^r$ in the product of $(1-x+x^2-x^3+......+x^{100})(1+x+x^2+x^3+.....+x^{100})$ is denoted by $T_r$. What is the value of $(T_{99}+T_{101}+T_{103})$

I don't know how to approach the question. Do I have to evaluate all of those T's separately? Or do they simplify into something beautiful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This polynomial is
$$\frac{1+x^{101}}{1+x}\frac{1-x^{101}}{1-x}
=\frac{1-x^{202}}{1-x^2}=1+x^2+x^4+\cdots+x^{200}.$$
What are $T_{99}$ etc.?

Comment: +1 Thanks for the quick answer. Completely forgot about geometric series.

Comment: This was a mcq in an exam, but none of the options had zero. Do you think it's a mistake?

Comment: Another was to see all these coefficients are zero is to observe that the expression is an even function of $x$. @SmarthBansal